# What is maybe_convert_objects good for?

Tags: pandas

I'm profiling the timing of one od my functions and I see that I spent alot of time on pandas DataFrame creation - I'm talking about 2.5 seconds to construct a dataFrame with 1000 columns and 10k rows:

```
def test(size):
samples = []
for r in range(10000):
    a,b = np.random.randint(100, size=2)
    data = np.random.beta(a,b ,size = size)
    samples.append(data)
return DataFrame(samples, dtype = np.float64)
```

Running `%prun -l 4 test(1000)` returns:

[image]

Is there anyway I can avoid this check? This really not seems Tried to find out about this method and ways to bypass here but didnt find anything online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pandas must introspect each row because you are passing it a list of arrays. Here are some more efficient methods in this case.

```
In [27]: size=1000

In [28]: samples = []
    ...: for r in range(10000):
    ...:     data = np.random.beta(1,1 ,size = size)
    ...:     samples.append(data)
    ...: 

In [29]: np.asarray(samples).shape
Out[29]: (10000, 1000)

# original
In [30]: %timeit DataFrame(samples)
2.29 s ± 91.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

# numpy is less flexible on the conversion, but in this case
# it is fine
In [31]: %timeit DataFrame(np.asarray(samples))
30.9 ms ± 426 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

# you should probably just do this
In [32]: samples = np.random.beta(1,1, size=(10000, 1000))

In [33]: %timeit DataFrame(samples)
74.4 µs ± 381 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Comment: Hi, this is great! thanks alot. Regarding the last option.. Well, I can't do that cause every array is composed of different a,b parameters. I'll change the question to reflect that so it would be clear. Thanks again :)